# Getting Bulgarian Tourist Visa to apply for 'Citizenship by Investment'

Tags: bulgaria, iran-citizens

I hold an Iranian passport. I live in Turkey on a one-year tourist visa. Besides, I have a minimum money to buy Bulgarian government bonds [to get permanent residency](https://www.artoncapital.com/global-citizen-programs/bulgaria/) leading to the citizenship (which is about 500k Euro).

There is a problem that I do need your helps, please:

There is no government-official website for 'Bulgarian Citizenship by Investment'. And, the people working in Bulgarian embassy in Turkey don't know about such a program though they didn't deny its existence either (they told me that I will get better information when I am **in** Bulgaria. BUT there are many many websites telling **the same** requirements for getting that permanent residency which makes me believe that it is not a scam.

On the other hand, I hold a politically weak passport with weak circumstances for a tourist-visa-applicant i.e. I don't work and I don't study and the like so have not a strong proof of leaving Bulgaria after visiting (though I don't want to leave if I can extend my stay **legally**).

PS there is no as 'low'-minimum required investment in EU as Bulgarian Bond Program leading to citizenship esp without language test which I will not be obliged to make a huge donation (like Malta). Otherwise my aim to get residency/citizenship of any EU country. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am neither a Bulgarian nor do I live there, but I have close family and business relationships to Bulgaria. I am a resident and citizen of another EU country.

What I was able to find out is: There is no website because there is no such programme, in the sense that Bulgaria does not "market" itself that way. On the other hand, that doesn't necessarily mean that it will not be possible to gain residency and in a later step citizenship in Bulgaria. And it does not mean that there wouldn't be companies which will be happy to take your money to help you find out. The question is what you can agree with them about paying only on success.

But please also double-check if you will be allowed to travel into othe EU countries as long as you are only a resident but not a citizen. Bulgaria is not yet a member of the so-called Schengen area and will likely not become one anytime soon. This means that you will possibly have the same visa requirements as a Iranian national if you want to travel to Germany / UK / France with or without your Bulgarian residency.